# Why am I getting an IndexError for a (seemingly) properly-split string?

Tags: python, indexing, split, urllib2

I currently have a script that is supposed to fetch and return the number of clicks a Bit.ly link has. I start out by gathering and reading the data from a Bitly url, which I appear to be doing correctly.

```
    bitly_data = "https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/link/clicks?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&link=http://bit.ly/"+link
    src = urllib2.urlopen(bitly_data)
    src = src.read()
```

When `link` is something such as `TY8lnd`, `src` is a string that looks something like

> {"status_code": 200, "data": {"units": -1, "tz_offset": -4, "unit":
>   "day", "link_clicks": 535}, "status_txt": "OK"}

I now want to parse this string to get just the numerical value after `link_clicks`. I figured the best way to do this was by making two splits.

```
    src=src.split('clicks": ')
    src = str(src[1])
    clicks = src.split('}, "status')
    clicks = clicks[0]
```

When I run this, clicks does, ultimately, equal the correct number and only that. However, Terminal returns an IndexError for the line `src = str(src[1])`. I tried getting rid of the `str()` but this had no effect. An understanding as to why I am getting this error despite the end value being corrected would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the Traceback in its entirety:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.9-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1701, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.9-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1689, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.9-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.9-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1360, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.9-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1358, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.9-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1344, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/Zach/Dropbox/bitly/bit.py", line 35, in settings
    src = str(src[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This response is json, as such, decode the json instead of trying to parse the string.

```
>>> import json
>>> resp = '{"status_code": 200, "data": {"units": -1, "tz_offset": -4, "unit": "day", "link_clicks": 535}, "status_txt": "OK"}'
>>> resp_object = json.loads(resp)
>>> resp_object and resp_object.get('data', {}).get('link_clicks', 0) or 0
535
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick help! Following your instruction, though, I seem to be getting a TypeError: ``TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`` although, again, the proper number of clicks is being returned.

Comment: Provide the code that is doing this.  If you are getting a `TypeError` but still getting a value, then you are running more than one request or something else funky is going on.  If you have `None` in place of a valid object then you wouldn't have clicks to get.

Comment: If you are getting None in the resp_object, then you can either check for it explicitly, or update like my last line update above and the None case as well as either missing `data` or `link_clicks` should at least show you `0` as a result.

Comment: Right. I am still only trying it using the example above, so returning None should not be an issue yet. Changing it to your updated line returns the click count but it is now an AttributeError: ``AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'``

Comment: My updated code is: ``bitly_data = "https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/link/clicks?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&link=http://bit.ly/"+link
 src = urllib2.urlopen(bitly_data)
 src = src.read()
 clicks = json.loads(src)
 clickamnt = clicks.get('data', {}).get('link_clicks', 0) or 0``

Answer (score 2):

`src` looks like it's JSON. Why not use the `json` module to read it directly?

For whatever reason if you don't want to use `json`, then read on:

The error is caused by you assuming that the substring you split on exists in the string you split, i.e. that `'clicks": '` is indeed a substring of `src`. If this is not the case (as I suspect it isn't when the error is raised), then `split` returns a list with only one element in it, and that element is `src`.

If you prefer that in this case, that `src[1]` should give you an empty string after calling `src = src.split('clicks": ')`, then you are better off using `str.partition`:

```
In [5]: somestr = 'prefixclicks: "suffix'

In [6]: somestr.partition('clicks: "')
Out[6]: ('prefix', 'clicks: "', 'suffix')

In [7]: somestr.partition('clicks: "')[-1]
Out[7]: 'suffix'

In [8]: somestr = 'prefixsuffix'

In [9]: somestr.partition('clicks: "')
Out[9]: ('prefixsuffix', '', '')

In [10]: somestr.partition('clicks: "')[-1]
Out[10]: ''
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

you can try this to find out the value of `link_clicks`, use `ast.literal_eval()`:

```
In [14]: import ast

In [15]: src=`{"status_code": 200, "data": {"units": -1, "tz_offset": -4, "unit": "day", "link_clicks": 535}, "status_txt": "OK"}`

In [16]: d=ast.literal_eval(src)

In [17]: d["data"]["link_clicks"]
Out[17]: 535
```

Comment: `literal_eval` could prove to be very dangerous if you don't trust the string you're `eval`ing

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I think it's `eval()`, which is considered dangerous. as docs says `this can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python expressions from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values oneself.`
http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Comment: `literal_eval` only evals simple types so no real danger, but I don't believe (and I may be wrong) that all json is *always* parseable in this way and if it isn't, this method is likely to produce an exception at some point.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` parses python literal syntax; `json.loads` parses [JSON](http://json.org/) syntax.  They're similar but subtly different (e.g. `True`/`False` in python vs `true`/`false` in JSON; only python allows single-quoted strings; only JSON has `nan` literal, ...) so it's important to use the right one.  Web APIs are waay more likely to return JSON, as is [the case for bit.ly](http://dev.bitly.com/formats.html).